# Delete multiple variables in Python 3 independently if they exist or not

Tags: python, spyder

With `del a, b, c` I can delete 3 variables at once if all variables `a, b, c` exist. However if a variable does not exists I get an error.

If I would like to delete variables `a, b, c` I could beforehand manually check its existence:

```
a = 1
b = 1
if 'a' in locals(): del a
if 'b' in locals(): del b
if 'c' in locals(): del c
```

This is quite cumbersome as I often want to delete multiple variables. Is there a more comfortable way similar to `del a, b, c`?

**Why do I want to delete variables?**

The Variable Explorer (e.g. in Spyder or other IDE) lists all my variables. For better overview I want to see only the important variables. Temporary variables that are used only for auxiliary purpose are not needed later and therefore do not have to appear in the Variable Explorer. Also memory is freed if auxiliary variables are deleted.

Comment: Why are you deleting the variables? Can't you simply not use them any more? Depending on your actual use, you probably want a `dict` or `list` to hold several items.

Comment: You might be misunderstanding how variables work. Whenever you print out this "overview", just don't print the ones you don't want. I think you need to post some more code or more thoroughly explain your goal.

Comment: Just ensure all variables are initialised, then delete them? `a=b=c=None` then `del a, b, c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A initialized variable, `a = 1`, is stored as a key-value pair, `{"a": 1}`, in a dictionary which is accessible via `locals`, `globals` built-ins.
Use `dict.pop` with a *default value* to remove the variable.

It is better to work with *care* when operating on `locals()`, `globals()` dictionaries, see comment of Mark Tolonen for details and reference to the doc.

```
#variables initialization
x1, x3 = 1, 3

# variables identifiers
to_del = "x1", "x2", "x3"

# delete the variables
for var_id in to_del:
    globals().pop(var_id, None)

# check
print(x1)
#NameError
```

---

EDIT: from the comment, in the form of a function

```
def g_cleaner(to_del:list[str]) -> None:
    """global cleaner"""
    for var_id in to_del:
        globals().pop(var_id, None)

g_cleaner(to_del)
print(x1)
#NameError: name 'x1' is not defined
```

alternative version

```
def g_cleaner(*to_del:list[str]) -> None:
    """global cleaner"""
    for var_id in to_del:
        globals().pop(var_id, None)

# for list-like arguments (unpacking)
g_cleaner(*to_del)
print(x1)
#NameError: name 'x1' is not defined

# for specific values
g_cleaner("x1", "x2") # quotes are needed!
print(x1)
#NameError: name 'x1' is not defined
```

Comment: Several times I want to delete multiple variables. How can I put this in a function? If I always have to write a loop to check existence it would be not comfortable.

Comment: For [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) note that "The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."

Comment: Could the inbuilt ```del``` be overwritten so that it works like ```g_cleaner``` ? One would then comfortabely call ```del x1,x2,x3``` and all variables are deleted also if they do not exist.

Comment: `del` is a language keyword and I think there is no easy way to do that... maybe going through CPython... or customize the source code, recompile it but... isn't easier to rename the function as `del` instead of `g_cleaner`?

Comment: if the variables aren't organized as list-like objects and you can modify the functions signature as `def g_cleaner(*to_del):`  (notice the `*`) and it will support  `g_cleaner("x1", "x3")` call and then unpack list-like objects `g_cleaner(*to_del)`

Comment: Could you add the last point in the answer? Is it possible to call the function in the way ```g_cleaner x1,x2,x3```, without brackets and quotes? As we can do this for ```del x1,x2,x3``` it should be also possible for a user-specified function.

Comment: quotes are needed! They are the key of the dictionary (see 1st line of the answer). Without the quotes will raise an error if the variable is not defined!

Comment: Why can I write ```del x1,x2,x3``` but have to  use quotes and brackets ```g_cleaner('x1','x2','x3')```? How can I avoid the dictionary?

Comment: [del](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=del#grammar-token-python-grammar-del_stmt) is a keyword, `g_cleaner` is a [function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions). Brackets represents a _call_ and are needed for every object which implement a `__call__` method (as functions do, -> check `print("__call__" in dir(g_cleaner))`)... and the `globals()`/`locals()` dictionaries are part of the game

Comment: How is it possible to treat ```g_cleaner``` also as a keyword to avoid brackets and quotes?

Comment: honestly I have no idea... post another question and some more experienced user _may_ tell you smt more. A possible way to bypass the problem is at _editor level_, make a macro that binds (for ex) `g_cleaner` with a  keyboard shortcut

Comment: How to create a keyword I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75302900/12842085

Answer (score 1):

One way that you could technically accomplish what you want would be this:

```
b1 = 1
b2 = 2
# b3 = 3 # commented to make it not exist
for name in {"b1","b2","b3"}:
  try:
    exec(f"del {name}")
  except NameError:
    pass
```

This will delete every variable name put in the list, which must be strings to avoid NameError right away.

However, I heavily recommend against this. The debugger is, as its name implies, only intended be used to debug. For actual program output you should use `print` statements, or some GUI if you want to be more friendly.

Example of some program output using f-strings:

```
print(f"Average {avg}, max {max_val}, mode {mode}, winner {winner.name}")
print(f"Loser: {loser.name}")
```

Edit:
Here's a modification of the other answer that allows use in a function, assuming you are only deleting locals.

```
def del_all(locals_v, *args):
    for v in args:
        locals_v.pop(v, None)
        

x1, x3 = 1, 3
del_all(locals(),"x1","x2","x3")
```

You could do `globals()` inside the function instead, as shown in the other answer, but then of course it only work if you were always working in the global scope, and wouldn't work when you are inside of any function.

Comment: Several times I want to delete multiple variables. How can I put this in a function? If I always have to write the try-except block it would be not comfortable.

Comment: Could the ```locals()``` in the function call be avoided and put into the function?

Comment: @granularbastard, not really because then they wouldn't be the correct locals. Also, Mark Tolonen points out that locals() shouldn't be edited anyway and might not work. You should just use the output functions (`print`) that python gives you to use. Trying to work this way is going to be a hassle because it's not how the language is supposed to give output.